# How can I play a online radio in html

Tags: html, audio, internet-radio

The given URL for the radio is **https://karthigaifm.radioca.st/streams/64kbps**

Stream type is Shoutcast
Port is 12000

I tried with this code, but it is not working.

```
<audio preload="none" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
       <source
           src="https://karthigaifm.radioca.st/streams/64kbps;"
       />
</audio>
```

Comment: Radio or audio??

Comment: Radio (online) you can check the radio with the link  https://karthigaifm.radioca.st/streams/64kbps

Comment: Note that the `<source>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never does in HTML.

Comment: I have removed that slash.. but still it is not working ------ Stream type is Shoutcast Port is 12000

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the semicolon at the end of the `src` string. Like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Audio Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio preload="none" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" src="https://karthigaifm.radioca.st/streams/64kbps" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried with this code.. but still it is not working ------ Stream type is Shoutcast,
Port is 12000

Comment: I edited my answer and posted the entire html document which I used to test it. It works in current versions of Firefox, Chrome and Edge on my machine. When I used your original code I got a warning on the console. With this code there is no warning. Do you see any console output when you use the code above?

Comment: If I create an HTML file only with the above code it's working, but I added the audio tag to my web page it does not work. I got the following error in console.-- Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mpeg: "https://karthigaifm.radioca.st/streams/64kbps".

Comment: Unfortunately I can not take a look at your code. I recommend that you start with the running minimal example and in small increments add more of your website's code until you find which part causes the issue. If you are stuck, post a new question on SO and explain what you have tried so far.